# Gradle modify build.gradle file through command line

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

Is it possible to add plugin through command line or programmatic option.  I'm trying to scan all build files and add a plugin if it's missing. Is there a way to add or remove plugins through command line.

Answer (score 0):

You can run `gradlew -I,--init-script` to run an initialization script

script example:

init.gradle (groovy)

```
apply plugin: EnterpriseRepositoryPlugin

class EnterpriseRepositoryPlugin implements Plugin<Gradle> {

    private static String ENTERPRISE_REPOSITORY_URL = "https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/repo"

    void apply(Gradle gradle) {
        // ONLY USE ENTERPRISE REPO FOR DEPENDENCIES
        gradle.allprojects { project ->
            project.repositories {

                // Remove all repositories not pointing to the enterprise repository url
                all { ArtifactRepository repo ->
                    if (!(repo instanceof MavenArtifactRepository) ||
                      repo.url.toString() != ENTERPRISE_REPOSITORY_URL) {
                        project.logger.lifecycle "Repository ${repo.url} removed. Only $ENTERPRISE_REPOSITORY_URL is allowed"
                        remove repo
                    }
                }

                // add the enterprise repository
                maven {
                    name "STANDARD_ENTERPRISE_REPO"
                    url ENTERPRISE_REPOSITORY_URL
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

docs here https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/init_scripts.html#sec:writing_an_init_script

Comment: Thank you. Will try and let you know.